# Handwritten character recognition with Gabor Filter and SVM with PCA

Tags: python, svm, pca, pattern-recognition, gabor-filter

I am trying to build a simple program in Python to classify handwritten digits (numbers) with the Gabor filter.

I am using the MNIST database (http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) for the training and the way I do it is by:

1. Calculating the phase of the Gabor filter for different orientations and scales.
2. Performing a PCA to reduce the dimensionality of the features (i.e. the phases).
3. Performing an SVM classification with a radial basis function as the kernel.

The code that I use is the following:

```
# Import required libraries
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn import svm
from skimage.filters import gabor
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import idx2numpy
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsOneClassifier

# Load NMIST dataset.
trainX = idx2numpy.convert_from_file("data/train-images-idx3-ubyte")
labelsX = idx2numpy.convert_from_file("data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte")

features = np.empty((1, 2))
labels = np.empty((1,))
mxm = 100
for i in range(mxm):
    image = trainX[i]
    for freq in np.arange(0.2,1.2,0.2):
        for orientation in range(0,360,45):
            filt_real, filt_imag = gabor(image,frequency=freq,theta=orientation) # Compute Gabor Filter on image i for a given scale and orientation
            phase = np.angle(filt_real + 1.0j*filt_imag) # Compute phase with real and complex part
            pca = PCA(n_components=2) # Initialize a 2-component PCA
            pca.fit(phase) # Fit phase in PCA
            curr = pca.transform(phase) # Feature reduction
            features = np.append(features,curr,axis=0) # Append features
            labels = np.append(labels,[labelsX[i]]*len(curr)) # Append labels

kf = KFold(n_splits=mxm)

counter = 1
for train, test in kf.split(features):
    print('Fold',counter)
    counter = counter + 1
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = features[train], features[test], labels[train], labels[test]
    clf = OneVsOneClassifier(svm.SVC(kernel='rbf'))
    clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
    print('Accuracy:',clf.score(X_test,y_test))
```

But for some reason, it gives me a very low accuracy (around 0.1). So, my question is: **Is SVM with PCA a good strategy for feature extraction of the Gabor filter?**

I do not want to use neural networks.

Comment: there are only 10 digits. So, you get 10% accuracy for free by predicting a random number. It looks like the model is not working correctly (but yes, SVM on top of Gabor is a reasonable idea)

Comment: Subjective: 2 components is definitely too few; scrapping PCA might not be a bad idea; so is dropping the kernel trick

Comment: @Marat So you’re suggesting that I use more dimensions for the PCA and that I don’t use the radial basis function as the kernel?

Comment: I'd rather drop PCA entirely and just work with raw filter output

Comment: @Marat But then I will have 70 dimensions because the images are 70 x 70. Wouldn’t that lead to overfitting?

Comment: You will have 70x70x5 =~ 25k dimensions (5 is the number of filters). MNIST dataset has 60K data samples, so with proper regularization (higher L1 reg will drop most input features) it should be ok

Comment: @Marat Yes, you're right. It worked. Do you think that with 2500 samples it is enough to train the model? Otherwise, if I take more, it takes forever to end. With 2500, I get ~90% accuracy.

Comment: That's 250 samples per digit. Given there are dozens of variations per digit, it will be challenging (although not completely impossible). It will also require a different architecture - the rule of thumb is at least 10 training samples per feature, so plan to have ~250 features max (PCA or ICA without filters might work)

Comment: @Marat Yes, that also works well. Thank you very much!